Code printing correct output too many times (CS50)
I am very new to coding and learning via Harvard's free CS50 course. Problem set 1 has been difficult, and I think I'm making it more challenging by doing things the hard way, ie I am trying to create functions for my code to get acclimated to how creating functions works. The task is to make a left-aligned pyramid with a height between 1 and 8. I've created functions to get the height from the user and to print the pyramid. The issue is with how the pyramid is printing. It prints correctly, but too many times. So, if the user types '3' when prompted for the height, it should print this:
  #
 ##
###

Instead, it prints that exact pyramid three times:
  #
 ##
###
  #
 ##
###
  #
 ##
###

What would the solution be to fix this based on my below code?
main:
{
    int n = get_height();

    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            print_row(n - i - 1, i + 1);
        }
    }
}

functions:
int get_height(void)
{
    int n;
    do
    {
        n = get_int("Height: ");
    }
    while (n < 1 || n > 8);
    return n;
}

void print_row(int spaces, int bricks)
{
    // Print spaces
    for (int j = 0; j < spaces; j++)
    {
        printf(" ");
    }
    // Print bricks
    for (int i = 0; i < bricks; i++)
    {
        printf("#");
    }
    printf("\n");
}


For anyone wondering, get_int() is a function that resides in cs50.h, a header tht Harvard provides for its CS50 course. It checks for incorrect input/overflow et cetera and continues prompting for input until a correct value is entered. It is used as a crutch in CS50 until students are familiar enough with the language's syntax/programming to do it themselves. (Similar functions are provided for float, string, et cetera.) To the OP, good luck for the next exercise, which I remember to be a full pyramid.

for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            print_row(n - i - 1, i + 1);
        }
    }

What the code is doing:

print_row() prints one single row.
The inner loop prints n rows. Or generates one pyramid.
The outer loop executes n times. So the outer loop is generating n pyramids (as the inner loop generates a single pyramid, n * 1 pyramid is equal to n pyramids ).

That's how your code is printing the pyramid n times. Because after generating the pyramid once, you repeat the process until you've generated n pyramids.
Simply remove the outer loop.

I appreciate your explanation on this, I think the reason I was confused and added the outer loop is because I was using two integers in the print_row function, so I thought I needed two of them in main() as well!

OP: "to get acclimated to how creating functions works"
Other answers have correctly diagnosed the problem as too many loops in main().
Since you are learning, here is a version that destructively decrements counters demonstrating slightly less code (less chance for a bug to hide somewhere.)
// #includes as required

// get_height() as per OP's code

void print_row( int spaces, int bricks ) {
    /* A comment to say, "Have removed this comment; its being only 'noise' */
    while( spaces-- )
        printf( " " ); // putchar( ' ' ); would work as well /* tutorial */

    while( bricks-- )
        printf( "#" );

    printf( "\n" );
}

int main( void ) {
    int n = get_height();
    int b = 0;

    while( n )
       print_row( --n, ++b ); // fewer spaces and more bricks each time

    return 0;
}

Each time print_row() is called, it receives a fresh pair of values for its use.

This code still uses the non-descript variable n in main(). A better name could be chosen.
Be wary of using i and j together in code.
Their similar appearance makes tracking down invisible bugs almost impossible at 4AM.
arr[i][j] & arr[j][i] look too similar in a small font or viewed with bleary eyes.
Plus, i and j are so generic they provide little information to a source code reader.

Comments like // Print spaces are considered noise.
Comments should explain why code has been written as it has:

// going left-then-right because right-then-left always fails on Thursdays

Don't explain the simple stuff. Let your code speak for itself.

x = x + 1; // increment x is excrement

Use comments sparingly and only to explain the "why" of code.

Advanced technique:
Acknowledging that the CS50 challenge is to print rows of spaces (SP) and hashes ('#'), here is a possible replacement for print_row() that almost fulfills the requirements.(Offered as an example of the power of C's function printf().)
void print_row( int spaces, int bricks ) {
    printf( "%*c%0*d\n", spaces+1, ' ', bricks, 0 );
}

Its output when int n = 5; is used in main():
     0 // <== definitely not a '#'
    00
   000
  0000
 00000

printf() is commonly used to pad its output with leading or trailing SP characters to achieve a desired width.
Not commonly used, printf() is also capable of producing multiple instances of the digit 0. In this example, the value 0 has been printed with increasing numbers of leading 0's. To the best of my knowledge, SP and 0 are the only characters that can be coaxed out of printf()'s capabilities for "padding" output.
This is something quite esoteric to store away, and come back to once you've learned much more about C and printf(). Its terseness, and especially its opacity, WOULD justify (require!?) a comment that explains to the casual reader what is going on with that one line of code.

"Their similar appearance makes tracking down invisible bugs almost impossible at 4AM." ==> I attest to this statement's veracity. Most times I am incrementing i instead of j or comparing against i instead of j. Especially when I am trying to type less and simply copy paste the first line. It is almost always a nuisance. :)

@Harith It's all part of "The Apprenticeship" :-) "Doh!" --Homer Simpson (with a facepalm)

@Fe2O3 Thank you so much for this! I was looking at my code and figured there was a way to make it more succinct, but couldn't conceptualize how to actually make it happen. I had to rack my brain and go through your code line by line to understand what it was doing, but that's good because it helped me to learn a few new things :) I already see the potential problems that can arise from using i and j together in code.. I'll be sure to use more descriptive names for my variables in the future. Thanks again for the tips!

@r0uthy You're welcome... There are, at present, 4 proffered answers to your question. If/when you're ready, it's customary for the OP to "accept" one as their preferred... You're free to choose...

Your code is incomplete, but it seems the problem is here.
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            print_row(n - i - 1, i + 1);
        }
    }

The inner loop prints the rows. The outer loop repeats the process. A giveaway is that j is never used. If n is 3 you'll get 3 rows repeated 3 times.
Adding printf("i: %d, j: %d\n", i, j) to show the value of i and j at each print_row call will be illustrative.
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            printf("i: %d, j: %d\n", i, j);
            print_row(n - i - 1, i + 1);
        }
    }


Sorry about the functions being incomplete when I first made the post, I am still getting used to how to paste the code. It kept telling me that the code was not properly formatted. Just removing the outer loop completely fixed the problem, so thank you! I still am not sure what the printf function you listed was supposed to do though. I tried compiling the program with that in there and it wouldn't work. I apologize for the ignorance, completely new to this. Your explanation of the loops helped me better understand what was actually going on there.

@r0uthy There was a typo in the printf call which has been fixed. It's just showing you the values of i and j so you can see how the loops are iterating as you print rows.

Thank you for fixing the typo! I tested it out in my code and made note of this for the future, because I'm sure it will be useful again. What does the %d stand for in this placeholder? I feel like the info on Google is a bit confusing. Search results indicate that it stands for "decimal", but the results also seem to imply that you can use %i or %d as the placeholder as it pertains to integers in the printf function

@r0uthy Yes, %d and %i are both for printing integers. I don't know why, but %d is more common. You can read up on all the printf options. Many languages make use of printf, not just C.

As others have identified the core issues with your loops, it may be instructive to see how we can remove some of these loops.

void print_row(int spaces, int bricks)
{
    // Print spaces
    for (int j = 0; j < spaces; j++)
    {
        printf(" ");
    }
    // Print bricks
    for (int i = 0; i < bricks; i++)
    {
        printf("#");
    }
    printf("\n");
}


Let's use printf to print the spaces for us by including a width field.
void print_row(int spaces, int bricks) {
    printf("%*s", spaces, "");

    for (int i = 0; i < bricks; i++) {
        printf("#");
    }

    printf("\n");
}

But apparently the longest line is 8 characters and printf's %s specifier can limit the length of a string printed. We only need to be able to print eight bricks.
void print_row(int spaces, int bricks) {
    char *bricks_str = "########";
    int line_len = spaces + bricks;

    printf(
        "%*.*s\n", 
        line_len,   // The amount of chars to pad the string to.
        bricks,     // The maximum number of characters to print
                    // from the string.
        bricks_str
    );
}


Thank you!! I would like to clarify what exactly is happening in your %s specifier.. I see that you added *.* in the middle of it. In the examples I've encountered so far with placeholders, the only time I've seen something between the percent sign and the specifier was something like %.20f for a float. I assume based on the arguments passed to the printf function, the first * prints the spaces, the . prints the bricks, and the last * determines the max number of bricks to print. I know you have the explanation next to it, but I am still a bit confused.

%M.Ns prints at most N characters from the string, padded to M characters long. By using * in place of literal numeric constants we can supply those as parameters to the function.
